# variable with condition in minizinc

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint-programming, minizinc

I am converting the model in aimms to minizinc.
In aimms, I have a variable defined as X with `index domain (k,i)`, where i,s,t is index of set Hour

Definition of X with indices i,s,t is:

```
sum((s,t) | (s <= i) and (t >= i), Pick(s,k,t) + OverPick(s,k,t))
```

I am not sure how to write this variable in minizinc.

Comment: I'm afraid it might be hard to help without knowing what the statement exactly means in aimms. Could you elaborate on the statement?

Comment: @Dekker1  X is total Inventory generated by two types of picking activities in area k. 
s is the picking time and t is the deliver time. where i is Inventory at time i between s and t.  And later I have a constraint to limit this X inventory to the capacity of area k: Inventory(k,i) <= MaxInventory(k) for k and i

Answer (score 0):

The MiniZinc syntax for the sum of items in `Pick` and `OverPick`, for a given area `k` between times `s` and `t` is:

```
var int: X = sum([Pick[i,k] + OverPick[i,k] | i in s..t]);
```

This assumes that `Pick[i,k]`, or `OverPick[i,k]`, contains the picking activity at time `i` in area `k`.

More information on constructing these kinds over statements can be found in the documentation on [Array Comprehensions](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.2.3/en/modelling2.html#arrays-and-sets)